# bind: override single SRV record only, forward the rest

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

### Prerequisites

To get our internal [libravatar](https://www.libravatar.org/) server working, I need to setup a SRV record for our public domain `company.com`:

```
_avatars._tcp.company.com.     IN SRV 0 0 80  avatars.internal
```

As you see the avatar server is on an internal domain that is not accessible from outside, thus the SRV record should not be available publicly.

### Problem

We have a BIND DNS server that resolves requests for internal domains. This server forwards requests forward `company.com` to the public DNS server (and *that should be kept* that way so we only have to manage public names on one server).

Now how can I override the `_avatars._tcp.company.com` SRV record on our local BIND server, while forwarding all other requests to the public server?

I know this is easy with subdomains (just define a master zone for the subdomain, done), but I fail to do that for SRV records for the main domain. What can I do?

### What I've tried

With the following setup, resolution works for the subdomain, but not for the main domain:

```
$ dig @localhost +short SRV _avatars._tcp.company.com
$ dig @localhost +short SRV _avatars._tcp.bookmarks.company.com
0 0 80 avatars.internal.
```

#### `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "_avatars._tcp.company.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db._avatars._tcp.company.com";
  allow-update { none; };
};

zone "bookmarks.company.come" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.bookmarks.company.com";
  allow-update { none; };
};
```

#### `/etc/bind/db.bookmarks.company.com`

```
$TTL    86400
@               IN SOA  @       root (
                                        2012082201      ; serial 
                                        3H              ; refresh
                                        15M             ; retry
                                        1W              ; expiry
                                        1D )            ; minimum

@               IN      NS      ns.company.com.
@               IN      A       192.168.1.41
_avatars._tcp.bookmarks.company.com.     IN SRV 0 0 80  avatars.internal.
```

#### `/etc/bind/db._avatars._tcp.company.com`

```
$TTL    86400
@               IN SOA  @       root (
                                        2012082201      ; serial
                                        3H              ; refresh
                                        15M             ; retry
                                        1W              ; expiry
                                        1D )            ; minimum
@                              IN NS          ns.company.com.
@                              IN SRV 0 0 80  avatars.internal.
_avatars._tcp.company.com.     IN SRV 0 0 80  avatars.internal.
```

(yes the last two lines are identical, but just to make sure)

Answer (score 2):

Add a zone for the specific name (`_avatars._tcp.company.com.`) to your internal DNS server, containing the single record you wish to override.

A SRV record is not special - it is just a DNS record, and it behaves like any other DNS record.

The override zone should look similar to what's below

```
$TTL    3600

@       IN      SOA     dev.company.com. root.company.com. (
                                   2009071505  ; serial
                                   10800       ; refresh
                                   3600        ; retry
                                   3600000     ; expire
                                   86400 )     ; minimum

@   IN  NS  inside-ns.company.com.

_foo.dev.company.com.       IN  SRV 0   0   80  google.co.uk.
```

Comment: I tried it; it did not work.

Comment: Provide more details - I promise you it does work if done correctly (created on the nameserver your inside clients are querying, no rogue nameservers usurping the record).

Comment: voretaq7, I 've updatet the question.

Comment: @cweiske Your zonefile for `_avatars.tcp.company.com1 is malformed (you need an NS record) -- named_checkzone should have caught this (and BIND should have cried about it when you loaded the zone). See my example (or your properly formatted file for `bookmarks.company.com`)

Comment: I've added the NS entry, and `named-checkzone` does not error out anymore. However, resolving still does not work and named-checkzone tells me: `warning: _avatars._tcp.company.com: bad name`. And yes, the bind error log says that the zone does not get loaded because of bad name.

Comment: @cweiske Fix your errors and the solution above will work.  If you're still having trouble with the zone you should ask a new question - comments aren't the right place to debug this sort of thing :)

Comment: My file is fine, it's just that `_tcp` is not allowed as part of the zone name, which invalidates your approach. Your example file is for the dev.company.com zone, defining _foo in there - that does not work for me because I need to overwrite _tcp.company.com without having access to company.com

Comment: @cweiske There is something amiss with your environment/file - if there were not BIND/`named-checkzone` would not issue warnings. `_tcp` is ***absolutely allowed** as part of a zone name -- if it weren't BIND would refuse to load *any* zone that contained it and SRV records would not work at all. (Also proof by counterexample: I created an override zone for `_foo._tcp` in my local DNS and it works  exactly as expected).  Please open a [new question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) for the zone-related troubleshooting (Or hang around here and see if anyone has another DNS override trick).